# placing functions to be used by any derived classes in the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, base-class, derived

```
class tabBase
{

public:
    tabBase() { }
    virtual ~tabBase() { }

    virtual void write() {}
    virtual void read() {}
    virtual void start() {}
    virtual void stop() {}
    virtual void connect() {}
    virtual void disconnect() {}
    virtual void openFile() {}
    virtual void closeFile() {}
    virtual void searchForText() {}

};

class tcpServerTab : public tabBase
{

public:
    tcpServerTab() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual ~tcpServerTab() { /* ...code... */ }

    virtual void write() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void read() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void start() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void stop() { /* ...code... */ }

};

class tcpClientTab : public tabBase
{

public:
    tcpClientTab() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual ~tcpClientTab() { /* ...code... */ }

    virtual void write() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void read() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void start() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void stop() { /* ...code... */ }

    virtual void connect() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void disconnect() { /* ...code... */ }

};

class plainTextTab : public tabBase
{

public:
    plainTextTab() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual ~plainTextTab() { /* ...code... */ }

    virtual void openFile() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void closeFile() { /* ...code... */ }
    virtual void searchForText() { /* ...code... */ }

};
```

Are there or can there be any design issues or unforeseen consequences with placing all possible functions to be used by any derived classes in the base class like the above example does?

Comment: It depends.  Are you going to be using these classes in a polymorphic fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure (force) that **all** of those functions will be implemented in **all** derived classes, you should make them **pure** virtual. Otherwise trying to predetermine and list all *possible* functions with empty bodies just does not make much sense. Judging by your example it seems that you need more than one level of inheritance.

Comment: What is a alternative design? Also, what would the extra level of inheritance look like?

Comment: No need to have *all* your functions in base class(es). If the function is only relevant to single derived class, no need to have it in base class at all. searchForText can be example of this. tcpServerTab and tcpClientTab can be derived from networkTab (which itself is derived from tabBase).